# Node js Cassandra Driver - configure retry policy

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax

Im using the DataStax driver for Cassandra in Node js, and I would like to configure the retry policy I could not find an example, I found a few in Java but noting for Node.

I came across these 2 links but could not derive how to implement this in Node.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/features/tuning-policies/#retry-policy

Please advise.

Comment: datastax docs are notoriously garbage.  thx for the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the retry policy in the [`ClientOptions`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/api/type.ClientOptions/):

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: ['host1', 'host2'],
  policies: {
    retry: new YourRetryPolicy()
  }
});
```